# What does a number above the 'staff' mean in tablature?

Tags: tablature

What does a number above the 'staff' mean in tablature?

Such as the numbers 4 and 5 in this example.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the number of times you repeat the phase. Notice the two stacked asterisks (*'s) under numbers. Those are the tab analog to two dots in standard notation.

So, repeat the parts with two stacked asterisks on either side *x* number or times, 5 for the first bar and 4 for the second.